# why is the first prototype is correct while second is incorrect?

Tags: c++, function

In a question, the first prototype given below is called valid

```
int Function(int Tmp = Show());
```

while in the second case it is called as invalid declaration.Why?

```
float Function(int Tmp = Show(int, float));
```

here is the link to the question- http://www.indiabix.com/cpp-programming/functions/discussion-61

Comment: Without proper context the question at the link makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: The second one doesn't make any sense. What do you expect the default value to be?

Comment: C++ does not have "prototypes". Prototypes are a thing in C that are roughly equivalent to "declarations" in C++. (But C does not allow default arguments for function parameters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't pass any actual parameters to the Show() function in the second case. You would want something like

```
  float Function(int Tmp = Show( 1, 2.3 ));
```

The first case doesn't need parameters because it is presumably a call to a function that looks like this:

```
  int Show();
```

Answer (score 6):

The fact that `Show` is being used to establish a default argument value is a red herring.

`Show(int, float)` doesn't make sense in the context of *calling* that function `Show`, whereas `Show()` does.

When you call a function in C++, you supply parameter *values*, not the types.